# Surjective homomorphism $\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z/12\Bbb Z\to \Bbb Z/24\Bbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose we have a surjective group homomorphism $\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z/12\Bbb Z\to \Bbb Z/24\Bbb Z$. Then it seems to me like the generator of the $\Bbb Z$ factor must map to a generator of the cyclic group $\Bbb Z/24\Bbb Z$. Is this true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. For example, a generator of $\mathbb{Z}$ could be sent to $3$ and a generator of $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$ to $2$.